# How to route traffic from OPENVPN access server through VPN Client Gateway?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a Linux OpenVPN access server behind a firewall and is connected to the internet. I then have another separate internet connection with another firewall and a client windows machine behind that. My intentions are to be able to do a port scan on the same local subnet as the client machine through the VPN tunnel that I am creating. I have set up routes on said windows client machine to talk back to the host VPN network and vice versa. I am able to ping from the access server to the client IP but cannot receive any ICMP traffic back. I have done a Wireshark capture on the client machine and was able to see the ICMP packets come in but it states that no response was found as it was not replying. If anyone has any experience with this please help!

Comment: Cant provide a full answer based only on this description. Need at least a basic network diagram or even text outline with ip addresses and full openvpn configuration to get the whole picture. Whenever this happens usually one of the routing devices is missing either ip forwarding or it does not have the correct postrouting rules setup (masquerading/SNAT). You are in deep waters! Please provide full config and a network layout and i will try to pinpoint your problem.